# How to set a different background to the slide by using apache poi?

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint

When I set the background color for the slide, it will overwrite all the background colors. How can I set them separately?

Example：

```
        XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow();
        XSLFSlide createSlide = ppt.createSlide();
        createSlide.getBackground().setFillColor(Color.BLUE);

        XSLFSlide createSlide2 = ppt.createSlide();
        createSlide2.getBackground().setFillColor(Color.RED);
```

The background color will all turn red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[XSLFSlide.getBackground](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_4_0_0_FINAL/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/XSLFSlide.java?view=markup#l253) gets the background from master sheet in `slideMasters` if the `XSLFSlide` has not already a background. And after it is new created the `XSLFSlide` has not already a background.

So we need at least setting an empty background after creating the slide. Then `XSLFSlide.getBackground` gets this instead of the background from master sheet.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.*;

import java.awt.Color;

public class CreatePPTXSheetsDifferentBackground {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XMLSlideShow slideShow = new XMLSlideShow();
  XSLFSlide slide = slideShow.createSlide();
  if (slide.getXmlObject().getCSld().getBg() == null) slide.getXmlObject().getCSld().addNewBg();
  slide.getBackground().setFillColor(Color.BLUE);
  slide = slideShow.createSlide();
  if (slide.getXmlObject().getCSld().getBg() == null) slide.getXmlObject().getCSld().addNewBg();
  slide.getBackground().setFillColor(Color.RED);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreatePPTXSheetsDifferentBackground.pptx");
  slideShow.write(out);
  out.close();
 }
}
```